# How to create user input dependent form elements?

Tags: forms

I have created a form and it has multiple elements. Is there a way to show specific form elements depend on a slelect box selected value.
For an example my select box has 2 options. if i select option 1, form will show a text box after the select box. if the selected option is 2, form will show a another select box
after the first select box.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and quite easy. Read up on the #states value in the [drupal form api documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#states). I am assuming this is for Drupal 7...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.deckfifty.com/blog/2012-11/drupal-form-api-conditional-fields this link has the answer i want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created the form or fields using webform builder, you can use the [conditional_fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module which is quite easy to configure and very flexible.